# LibGDX - change the inside color, not border

Tags: colors, libgdx

I have a rounded square texture, drawn in paint, with black border. How can I change only the inner color without changing the border color?

**EDIT:** I did it, but I want to ask if it can be done without using another texture? I also wonder if there is a connection between this and 9patch as in scaling. Can we use that or is there something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by tile? Is it a sprite or are you using `ShapeRenderer`?

Comment: @MennoGouw I've edited my question.

Comment: Just use another texture then? Otherwise you can look into masking or you can also create your own shader but that requires shader language.

Comment: You still haven't answered the questions. Unclear what you're asking. How are you drawing the texture?

Comment: I have png file, I put it into the assets folder. I added it as Texture. In main class, I use spritebatch to draw this texture. And I want to change the inner color, not change the whole texture color.

Comment: @MennoGouw Thanks, using another texture solved it. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tint whatever it is what you are drawing, using SpriteBatch. This means that color you specify is multiplied with the color of the image. For example if your image is a white rounded rectangle with a black border and you tint it using the color purple then the inside will be purple and the border will remain black. You didn't provide enough information to be more specific. But if you are for example using the `Sprite` class then you can use the `setColor` method to tint it. Likewise if you are using the `Image` class. If you are drawing the "texture" directly using `SpriteBatch` then you can use the `setColor` method of the `SpriteBatch`.